# What is the secure way to store public and primary keys?

Tags: java, security, session, encryption, cryptography

I'm using AES with RSA encryption and decryption for client and server's secure communication. I've been told to hardcode a public key in Javascript for Login purposes with its associate private key hardcoded in Java. The same applies for Signup process but the keypair of Login and Signup will be different.

Now the tricky part is, I've to generate a keypair for each user once he logged in and use that keypair for that particular user until he logout or his session timed out. Assuming I'm having 1000+ users, I've to generate the key everytime a new session is created and maintain the same keypair for that user until logout or timeout.

These are my thoughts on how to store the Public and private key

1) We've to define the name for the file before saving the public and private key to a file. We can use the logged in user's username to add it to saved file like - Dan.Public.key and Dan.Private.key , If it's for another user - Ken.Public.key, Ken.Public.key  (Dan and Ken are the usernames)

Even if the user "Dan" logout or his session times out, my filter will create a new private and public key once he login again and save the key again to Dan.Public.key and Dan.Private.key, so it'll automatically overwrite the last used key files of the same user. By defining the file names like this, I can manage it for any number of users without have to worry about security (Ofcourse I've to perfectly configure on who can access the keys folder). Coming to my Real-Time issue, my application is API-call, so there is no session at all. The only way to manage session is to handle it by generating a UUID and using that to maintain the user's session and keeping logs of the user.

If I've to fetch the public and private key for every call, first I've to check the DB to find the respective username which associates with the current UUID. This is a very bad way in long run. Also I can give name to key files using UUID instead of username, but it'll damage my server near soon, coz there will no overwriting of already saved files due to the unique UUID (There is no way to overwrite a last used key file, coz every new UUID is unique)

2) I can simple store the public and private key to the database along with the generated UUID, so I can simply fetch those keys for encryption and decryption by using `.add(Restrictions.eq("UUID_USER",UUID));`  But I'm worried about the security when storing it directly in DB.

Note: Until now I don't know how to store the public and private keys in a database.

I've used PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 with an iteration count of 100000+ , salt of 16 byte to prevent leakage of passwords even if the hacker gets the database. Comparing the high security for password storage and pretty dump idea of string private and public key directly in DB, I feel a much greated gap between those two security levels.

I've read a little about storing keys in Keystore, but I've no idea how it works. If I've choosen to store the keys in DB, can I use some kind of hardcoded encryption and decryption in java for those keys, but that will slower the process time for every click which will be heavyweight for the server if more users are logged in at same time. I'm not even at a medium level when considering cryptography coding, but I dont want to implement a high secure system for one part and 0 secure system for another part. If anyone have worked on these kind of applications before, kindly share the way of how you're handling the storage of public and private keys.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the user keys are used to either sign the data sent from client to server or encrypt data sent from server to client.

You really shouldn't store the private key of the user on the server (or generate for that matter). It is better to generate the key pair on the client and send the public key to the server encrypted with the public key of the server.

The server (and developers/ops) never receives the user private key and cannot impersonate the user. Everytime the user logs in, a new key pair is generated and the public key is overwritten in the database.

Note that this doesn't entirely protect you from attacks, because a network-based attacker may simply inject additional JavaScript to steal the user private keys or instruct the client to send all information directly to the attacker. The only way to solve this, is to use SSL/TLS.